# Simple demonstration of imputation data leakage?

Tags: cross-validation, data-imputation, data-leakage

I'm aware that it's best practice to do all pre-processing within train-test splits, including data imputation. At least, it's recommended not to use the test data to generate the imputation model for the training data. However, I'm struggling to find a demonstration (either a concrete example or something more abstract) for why imputing prior to splitting leads to data leakage (and over-optimistic model performance), *specifically in the case where the target variable is not used in the imputation model*. I'd be very grateful to see such a demonstration, preferably a concrete example.

Comment: you are already introducing bias by not using the target variable

Comment: @seanv507 will this lead to an over optimistic estimate of model performance?

Comment: it will result in a wrong model. imagine you have a straight line y=x and x >5  (for eg x between -10 and 10) is missing. then without y you would impute x=-2.5 for all those missing points with y (and therefore x>5)...

Comment: @seanv507 well in this case you’re definitely not getting an over optimistic estimate of model performance, so I don’t see how it’s relevant to the question.